# Avoiding typescript index signature

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I am trying to make use of the EventDispatcher of three.js to add various events to my objects. the problem with my code is that I am getting back the callback interface and have to do some weird things to get to my actual object. all I need it the Object3D that is the target of the event function. But this function returns the callback interface instead.

Typescript has suggested me to use index signature for this but I would much rather get the actual object instead of the callback. Any ideas where I am going wrong to achieve this effect?

```js
export interface Callback {
    [x: string]: any; // I want to avoid this
    type: string;
    event(callback: Callback): void;
}
```

```js
    this.scene.addObject('planetCore',
      new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry(0.3, 1),
        this.materialLibrary.getMaterial('planetCore')),
      {
        type: 'update', event: (callback: Callback) => { // this object should be the Object3D instead...
          const target = callback.target as THREE.Object3D; // Also want to avoid this

          target.rotateX(-0.002);
          target.rotateY(-0.003);
        }
      });
```

```js
  addObject(name: string, object: THREE.Object3D, callback?: Callback) {
    this.sceneData.set(name, object);
    super.add(object);

    if (callback) {
      THREE.EventDispatcher.call(object);
      callback.target = object;
      object.addEventListener(callback.type, callback.event);
    }
  }
```